# The beginning of HTML TItles of the site are the same for same pages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, title

I have 4 Firefox windows open and in the Windows Task Bar, I see 4 **Newest Questions - ...** Firefox windows. I have to mouse over them to figure out which one is which.

I'm thinking **SO - Newest Quest...**,  **SF - Newest Quest...**, **SU - Newest Quest...**, & **MS - Newest Quest...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The favico icons next to each one should tip you off about which is which.

Putting the site first is bad information design, the most relevant thing is the content *not* the site.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the tabs feature of Firefox? That way you would be able to see the site icons as well to help differentiate.